# Firebase security rules not triggering when using Firebase's Firestore Lite inside of a Cloudflare worker

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, cloudflare

I am not able to get Firebase security rules working with Firestore Lite (`firebase/firestore/lite`); using normal Firestore does not work in Cloudflare workers (`firebase/firestore`).

I am authenticated, I am successfully able to see a loggedIn user via `currentUser` on the worker, but making requests to get data from Firebase and trying to secure such access points does **NOT** work

I have the following security rule in Firebase:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And I have the following Firebase code firing inside of a GQL query:

```js
import { DocumentData, collection, getDocs, doc, getDoc, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

// GQL query resolve:
resolve: async (_, { id, limit, startAfter }) => {
    // Retrieve product from the database
    const aisRef = collection(this.firebase.db, 'sites');

    let aisQuery = query(aisRef, where('template', '==', 'ai'), where('projectId', '==', id));

    const snapshot = await getDocs(aisQuery);

    // Rest of the code...
},
```

and finally, here's the Firebase initialization code:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, initializeAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import { DecodedIdToken } from '@fiboup/hono-firebase-auth';

export class Firebase {
    private app;
    public auth;
    public jwtPayload?: DecodedIdToken;

    constructor(apiKey: string, authDomain: string, databaseURL: string, projectId: string, appId: string, userPayload?: DecodedIdToken) {
        this.app = initializeApp({ apiKey, authDomain, databaseURL, projectId, appId });
        this.auth = initializeAuth(this.app);

        this.jwtPayload = userPayload;
    }
    public get db() {
        return getFirestore(this.app);
    }

    public get userPayload(): FirebaseJwtPayload | undefined {
        return {
            ...this.jwtPayload,
            ...{
                picture: () => {
                    try {
                        return new URL(this.jwtPayload?.picture);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Failed to get firebase user picture', error);
                        return undefined;
                    }
                },
                auth_time: new Date(this.jwtPayload?.auth_time * 1000),
                iat: new Date(this.jwtPayload?.iat * 1000),
                exp: new Date(this.jwtPayload?.exp * 1000),
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Even though the user is signed in, and I am able to grab the `currentUser` properly by verifying the token, Firebase's rules always returns the following error:
[image: Error code in the console]

How can I tell Firebase that the user is signed in? For some reason when the security rule is supposed to verify such user, `request.auth` is null.

I really don't want to change the DB mechanism, and I don't want to have an insecure database. Any advice would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: We can't see `PrivateApiSchema` and how it's using your `Firebase` object.  I suggest reworking this example to be the absolute **minimal** code that reproduces the problem so we don't have so much to trace through here. Ideally it's possible for someone to simply copy what you show and use it to observe the same results.

Comment: @DougStevenson, done. I added more context. I would be happy to add a complete example but this project is not open source, but I believe these are all the important pieces needed to track down any issues.

Comment: There are still a lot of symbols we can't see here.  How about removing GraphQL entirely and just show how you use Firestore lite to make a query that doesn't work the way you expect?  That's what I mean by "minimal".  GraphQL doesn't seem to be part of the issue here.  Show us only what's required.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have stripped out GQL from the question, and have left only the firebase code I am executing and having issues with.

Comment: I don't see any code that is signing the user in. Can you reduce this to a single code snippet that reproduces the problem? It might also be helpful if you `console.log(getAuth().currentUser)` right before you call to Firestore and check the output.